# Laplace's equation with the inner unclosed edge

Tags: harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, constraints

Hello I'm Owen and I'm new here.
Recently I was working on a boundary element problem about the Laplace equation. The basic Laplace equation is as follows:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\Delta \varphi=0 & \\
\varphi=\bar{\varphi}, & \text{on the boundary } \mathrm{S}_{\varphi} \\
\mathrm{q}=\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \mathrm{n}}=\overline{\mathrm{q}}, & \text{on the boundary } \mathrm{S}_{\mathrm{q}} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $S_{\varphi}$ denotes Dirichlet boundary, $S_{q}$ denotes Neunmann boundary.
With the Green's function, we can derive a boundary integral equation like:
$$
\varphi(i)=\int_{\mathrm{S}}[\mathrm{G}(i, j) \mathrm{q}(j)-\mathrm{F}(i, j) \varphi(j)] \mathrm{dS}(j), \quad \forall i \in \mathrm{V}
$$
Combining this formula with BEM, we can calculate the value inside the region from the value on the boundary.

**However, I can't solve the cases with non-closed lines inside**, for example:A circular area has a non-closed constraint line inside, which causes the area enclosed by the circular outer contour and the constraint inner contour to be non-closed, which also makes the Green function impossible.

How should I correctly calculate the effect of the right red constraint line on the inner area.

Thanks

Comment: Where must the boundary data be supplied so that the Laplacian problem is well posed?

Comment: Just provide a closed boundary data, such as a closed circular boundary or a closed circle with a few holes in it, so long as the boundary is closed, then the Laplacian problem is solved.@Sal

Comment: If you have a non-closed line inside the region of interest, then you are not providing the boundary data on a closed boundary